# Best way to display data from database to a VB.Net app?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making my loan management application right now, I just want to ask what is the best way to view loan data in VB.Net? By the way, I'm using MySQL as a database.

Comment: I think its up to you, you can add a grid and bind it to your database, so you can visualize your data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is something I hope that can help read off SQL, it might need a bit of editing and building off but I still hope it helps.

```
Dim conString As String = "data source=ServerName;" & _
                            "initial catalog=DBName;" & _
                            "integrated security=SSPI;" & _
                            "persist security info=false;"

Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection(conString)

conSQL.Open()

Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand()
cmdSQL.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT FieldName1, FieldName2 FROM MyTable"

Dim adptSQL As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
adptSQL.Fill(myDataSet)

conSQL.Close()

With myDataSet.Tables(0)
    For rowNumber As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
        With .Rows(rowNumber)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Field1: {0}, Field2: {1}", _
                                            .Item(0).Value.ToString, _
                                            .Item(1).Value.ToString))
        End With
    Next
End With
```